# how do determine the distribution of outcomes for a given probability?

Tags: probability-distributions

For a game I generate various block types given certain odds. Say, there's a $0.001$ chance for the karma block. If a typical game has $600$ blocks, what's the distribution of games that have $0$ karma blocks, $1$ karma blocks, $2$ karma blocks, etc.

I've tried reading the wikipedia page on probability distributions, but I can't figure out how it applies to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the binomial distribution because the probability of each block being karma or not-karma (whatever that means), that is, the probability of a success or a failure in each trial is constant and independent of the other trials.

In general, the probability that there are k successes out of n trials in a binomial distribution is ${n\choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ (where p is the probability of a success). In your case the probability of 'k' "karma blocks" would be ${600 \choose k} (0.001)^k(0.999)^{600-k}$.

What's actually happening is you determine there must be exactly $k$ karma-blocks, and that probability is $0.001^k$. The rest of the 600 have to be failures, hence $0.999^{600-k}$ (because if it's not a success, it's a failure, 1-0.001=0.999). And you don't care about order so you multiply by the number of different orders there could be for k karma blocks in 600 blocks, which is $600 \choose k$

Comment: Adding to this answer, the Normal Distribution is often used when $n$ is large. There are some other conditions which should be satisfied as they are mentioned on the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation).

Comment: @Jerry Oh please! The Poisson distribution is a far better candidate than the normal distribution in this case.

Comment: @DilipSarwate sure. I never did Poisson. My class stopped at Normal...

Answer (score 0):

A very good approximation to the desired probabilities is
$$P\{X = n\} = e^{-0.6}\frac{(0.6)^n}{n!}, ~~ n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$$
This is called the Poisson approximation to the binomial distribution (cf. @Zen's answer)
and applies whenever $n$ is large ($600$ in your case) and $p$ is small ($0.001$ in your
case) while $np = 0.6 \ll n$.